# Extracting a string value from a pipe-separated string in a table column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm an Oracle newbie. 
I have a column in my table that contains a pipe(|)-separated string such as this:

```
uguyguyguyguyguy|0737494110|noreply@xxyyxx.se|E:\PROD_ActionMarketer\Program\Apsis\ApsisREST.exe|E:\PROD_ActionMarketer\Temp\TempApsisAdmin.skv|SENDEMAIL|"LIST=Daily SMS SPL"|1015832
```

As you see the penultimate value begins with "LIST=". I want to extract the value after this string i.e. "Daily SMS SPL" to be able to compare it with another column in another table. I want to obtain this value ("Daily SMS SPL") using a `SELECT` query if it's possible.

So let's say the table name is `MYTABLE` and the name of the column is `MYCOLUMN`.

Comment: Have a look at REGEXP_SUBST (e.g. https://community.oracle.com/thread/1022453?tstart=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT SUBSTR(surname,1
                 ,INSTR(surname,'"',1,1)-1) FROM
(SELECT SUBSTR(column
                 ,INSTR(column,'LIST',-1)+5
                 ) AS surname
     FROM table)
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e4eb/8)